# DXA Framework supports multiple .NET versions?

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

We started to create a new web application and used the sample in the DXA framework.
We use Tridion 9.0 and want to build it for .NET 4.7.2.

The DXA Framework is published in nuget as package "Sdl.Dxa.Framework.Web8 2.2.6" and doesn't support .NET 472. It is build for .NET 4.6.2.

I downloaded the source  [here](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/archive/DXA_2.2.6_Hotfix.zip) and make build it to .NET 4.7.2, that works.

My questions are:

*1.] Is that the way to go?*

Microsoft has support for multiple versions in Visual Studio and for Nuget packages.

*2.] Will that be implemented?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DXA NuGet packages are indeed built against .NET FW 4.6.2, but you can use them in a .NET 4.7.2 (or even 4.8) Web App too.

There is no need to compile the DXA Framework yourself against 4.7.2.

The reason why DXA Framework typically isn’t compiled against the latest-greatest .NET Framework is that it is possible to use .NET assemblies compiled against lower .NET versions in higher .NET runtimes, but not vice versa.